# CSS style doesn't work on IE7 bug

Tags: internet-explorer, styles

I met a bug on IE7 with style:

I have several elements(`ul`) generated by javascript:

```
var wrap = document.createElement("ul");
wrap.setAttribute("data-elem", "tabbody");
wrap.setAttribute("class", "popup-juji-list clearfix");

widget.insertBefore(wrap , flag);
```

**Update render result**:

`<ul data-elem="tabbody" class="popup-juji-list clearfix" data-videodownload-elem="selectedBody">`

but these `ul` elements can't have any style of `popup-juji-lis` or `clearfix`

But when I used IE7 develop tool, do some change on class, like add a space between `popup` and `clear`, or exchange them position, the style could work again

Does anyone ever met the bug before, how can I fixed it?

Comment: If the question is "Does anyone ever met the bug before, how can I fixed it?" The answer is : "It's IE... obviously we've all experienced it. If the question is how to do it, we will need more information. Maybe tell us what's the result in firebug.

Comment: @MichaelVilleneuve: Everything would go fine on firefox, chrome, even the other version of IE

Comment: I know, it's always like that. Copy Paste the source code of the "<li>" that are generated so that I can help you.

Comment: @MichaelVilleneuve: I have update the generate code, and update the render result